# Ubuntu Update problem | 16.04 ; cannot complete the update

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, update-manager

whenever I run :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this message below:

```
W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

W: The repository 'ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I used

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and comment or remove lines that include cdrom. eg:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus - Release amd64 (20160420.3)]/ xenial main restricted>
```

I was be able to remove it. when I ran `sudo apt-get update` , got the error message below.

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

could anyone shed some light on this please ? Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The ppa you are using does not have packages available for 16.04, that is the meaning of the 404 error.

Disable the ppa or contact the maintainer.

See also [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: I can disable the ppa easily. However, I  need it for programming purposes. if I were to contact the maintainer how would I go about it ? Thank you so much

Comment: @DilAzat  Try https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-on-rails

Comment: From https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-on-rails you can file a bug report, contact the team, post to the mailing list, etc. If you need the package, and there is no ppa, you will have to compile from source.